# Career dilemma for a 32 year old windows Desktop SE

Tags: job-change, career-switch

Currently, I am "Senior SE" in a manufacturing equipment company. I do C#,WCF WPF, C(PLC) for desktop and to control hardware. Previously exposed to C++, ABAP, Java etc. But not in depth. I am like jack of all trades knowing about different electrical electronic hardwares and SW components just to certain extent to maintain and fix bugs. I have a major in EEE and masters specialization in automation and control( Robotics, neural networks etc) with a dissertation on machine learning related stuff.

My current issues are 
1. " My kind of job is very limited". It is not every city.
2. Pay is not good.

So, I am thinking to change to machine learning with online courses and project since I have some project and academic knowledge on that. My other choice is to go in to web but it will not be a wise decision with my current experience.

Did somebody experienced something like this in their career? Please share if you have any perspective on this

Comment: Why machine learning rather than embedded/IoT? That seems to fit your background more.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Considered.. But, Frankly, biased towards machine learning as it is a hot topic and I have some academic knowledge already.. But I like to try courses on both to decide..

Comment: Combine the two and you get edge ML/IoT, which is a pretty hot field as well and has lots of applications in manufacturing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of this as mid-career professional growth rather than a career restart in a new field. Your training and work experience are potentially very valuable to some employer.

Try drafting a resume for yourself explaining how you are a great candidate for a ML job involving real world data. You are! Then search for job openings that interest you, and compare your draft resume with requirements.

That will show you what, if anything, you need to learn before applying for those jobs.

Then apply to a few of them for the practice.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you mentioned being "biased towards machine learning as it is a hot topic and I have some academic knowledge already".

Don't assume too much from the hot-topicness of ML. It's been a hot topic for long enough to build up a large group of ML-educated entry-level developers. That's not to say that you should dismiss the idea of retraining, but you should consider whether it puts you ahead of the crowd. Your jack-of-all-trades real world experience counts for a lot more than you might think, and you should give companies a chance to hire you for that skillset, before you transition from being a senior SE/EE engineer to being a junior ML engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Most devices (phones, robots, doorbells...) being manufactured now require a mix of mechanical, electronics, and software design. You have the skills and experience to work in a design group as the person who can talk to everyone and work on problems involving a mix of hardware and software issues.